# How do I stop a deleted purchased apps from continously charging me?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I bought this Starmaker app at the App Store for Iphone which cost me $1.79. I thought that I would be charged just one time. But every week, I have been getting email notifications that I am continously being charged $1.79 for each week. I deleted the app from my Iphone but they are still charging my credit card. How do I stop this?

Comment: You are being charged by Apple?

Comment: The notification that I get is from Itunes Store so I suppose that is from Apple.

Comment: Tell your credit card company, they will stop it.
Also contact Apple about this issue, they can refund it if you really paid more than once.

Answer (score 11):

It's likely you made an in-app purchase of some sort of subscription. To check and deactivate the subscription, manage you Apple ID account in iTunes by clicking `View My Apple ID` in the `Store` menu.

[image]

Enter your password and on the resulting page you should see subscriptions listed under `Settings` with the number of subscriptions.

[image]

Click on the `Manage` link to the right. There you should be able to cancel any recurrent subscription plans.

Answer (score 3):

You should go to Apple [Support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes) and contact the iTunes team. They are the only ones who can fix this.